# Ajax, add to database and update div content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Okay, so I am trying to use ajax. I've tried several ways of doing this but nothing is working for me. I believe the main problem I have is that ajax won't add to my database, the rest is managable for me.

Here is the relevant ajax-code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log($("going to attach submit to:","form[name='threadForm']"));
$("form[name='threadForm']").on("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var message = $("#message").val();
   //assumming validate_post returns true of false(y)
   if(!validatepost(message)){
       console.log("invalid, do not post");
       return;
   }
   console.log("submitting threadForm");
   update_post(message);
});
});

function update_post(message){
    var dataString = "message=" + message;
    alert(dataString);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'post_process.php',
        async: true,
        data: dataString ,
        type: 'post',
        success: function() {
            posts();
        }
    });
 }

 function posts(){
     console.log("getting url:",sessionStorage.page);
     $.get(sessionStorage.page,function(data){
         $("#threads").html(data);
     });
 }

 function validatepost(text){
     $(document).ready(function(){

    var y = $.trim(text);
    if (y==null || y=="") {
        alert("String is empty");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    }); 
  }
```

Here is the post_process.php:

```
<?php
    // Contains sessionStart and the db-connection
require_once "include/bootstrap.php";   

$message = $con->real_escape_string($_POST["message"]); 

if (validateEmpty($message)){
    send();
}

function send(){
    global $con, $message;

    $con->create_post($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['category'], $_SESSION("subject"), $message);
}

//header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

And lastly, here is the html-form:

```
<div id="post_div">
<form name="threadForm" method="POST" action="">
    <label for="message">Meddelande</label><br>
    <textarea id="message" name="message" id="message" maxlength="500">

    </textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Skicka!" name="post_btn" id="post_btn"><br>
</form>
```

create_post is a function I've written, it and everything else worked fine until I introduced ajax.

As it is now, none of the console.log:S are getting reached.

Ajax works when jumping between pages on the website but the code above literally does nothing right now. And also, it works if I put post_process.php as the form action and don't comment out the header in post_process-php.

I apologize for forgetting some info. I am tired and just want this to work.

Comment: You have `onclick="update_post()"` in your submit button, but you do not prevent the default form submit (ie. `event.preventDefault();`), so your form is most likely posting/refreshing, so the `$.ajax()` never has time to be called/run.

Comment: Your whole code is dependant on this conditional statement `if(isset($_POST['subject'])){` yet I don't see a named element called `subject`. Plus, there's no mention of `session_start();`

Comment: Yes, it seems I left out some important information from my post that I just added. I've tried different ways of submitting the form, neither of which worked.

Fred: The sessionStart() is in the bootstrap-file that is included in post_process. Oh, I messed that up. I tried alot of different ways and I must have witten it wrong when I cleared up the code before I posted here. The info posted by $.ajax was called subject, not content when I tried it. And yes, the validate_post is a js-function in a separate file and everything worked until I introduced ajax.

Comment: Plus, what about `validate_post()`. I take it you have a JS function for that too?

Comment: Plus, this `create_post()` function. I doubt that's a core function.

Comment: POST variables rely on `name="xxx"` yours doesn't have one for subject. So, as it stands, your code is unclear and I can't make heads or tails as to what's supposed to be what and which function is located where.

Comment: Since you are using jQuery, why are you mixing vanilla XMLHTTP code in as well?  Why not just use jQuery all the way ...

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` during development and use `var_dump();` to track what is set or not.

Comment: Now you have `if(validateEmpty($message)){` but again, another missing function.

Answer (score 0):

I would first test the update_post by removing the button.submit.onclick and making the form.onsubmit=return update_post. If that is successful place the validate_post in the update_post as a condition, if( !validate_post(this) ){ return false;}

If it's not successful then the problem is in the php.

You also call posts() to do what looks like what $.get would do. You could simply call $.get in the ajax return. I'm not clear what you are trying to accomplish in the "posts" function.

Answer (score 0):

First you can just submit the form to PHP and see if PHP does what it's supposed to do. If so then try to submit using JavaScript:

```
$("form[name='threadForm']").on("submit",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //assumming validate_post returns true of false(y)
  if(!validate_post()){
    console.log("invalid, do not post");
    return;
  }
  console.log("submitting threadForm");
  update_post();
});
```

Press F12 in Chrome or firefox with the firebug plugin installed and see if there are any errors. The POST should show in the console as well so you can inspect what's posted. Note that console.log causes an error in IE when you don't have the console opened (press F12 to open), you should remove the logs if you want to support IE.

Your function posts could use jQuery as well as it makes the code shorter:

```
function posts(){
  console.log("getting url:",sessionStorage.page);
  $.get(sessionStorage.page,function(data){
    $("#threads").html(data);
  });
}
```

**UPDATE**

Can you console log if the form is found when you attach the event listener to it?

```
console.log($("going to attach submit to:","form[name='threadForm']"));
$("form[name='threadForm']").on("submit",function(e){
   ....
```

Then set the action of the form to google.com or something to see if the form gets submitted (it should not if the code works). Then check out the console to see the xhr request and see if there are any errors in the request/responses.

Looking at your code it seems you got the post ajax request wrong.

function update_post(message){
    console.log(message);

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'post_process.php',
    async: true,
    //data could be a string but I guess it has to
    // be a valid POST or GET string (escape message)
    // easier to just let jQuery handle this one
    data: {message:message} ,
    type: 'post',
    success: function() {
        posts();
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Something is wrong with your binding to the submit event. Here is an example how it can be done:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="the jquery library"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<form name="threadForm" method="POST" action="http://www.google.com">
    <label for="message">Meddelande</label><br>
    <textarea id="message" name="message" id="message" maxlength="500">
    </textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Skicka!" name="post_btn" id="post_btn"><br>
</form>
      <script>
$("form[name='threadForm']").on("submit",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("message is:",$("#message").val());
});   
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Even with message having 2 id properties (you should remove one) it works fine, the form is not submitted. Maybe your html is invalid or you are not attaching the event handler but looking at your updated question I think you got how to use document.ready wrong, in my example I don't need to use document.ready because the script accesses the form after the html is loaded, if the script was before the html code that defines the form you should use document ready.

Comment: I've updated the code in my original post.

Neither of the logs are getting reached, I've tried putting a few more console.log in different places throughout the submit-code and neither of those were reached either.

Comment: @Korpen make sure you put `$("form[name='threadForm']").on("submit",fun` after the form element because if that code executes when the form doesn't exist yet nothing will happen. If you have to put the code before the form then wrap it in a `$(document).ready`

Comment: I wrapped it in the $(document).ready and still nothing. This is so frustrating

Comment: @Korpen  Updated the answer. I assume you don't get any errors in the console, is the form submitted? It should not get submitted if you attach the event listener to it as preventDefault should prevent it from being submitted. I also assume that when you submit the form (no JS) the php page works so the problem is in the JavaScript.

Comment: The additional code you added in your update is firing so the problem must be with "$("form[name='threadForm']")...". And yes, the no JS-version is working like a charm.

Comment: @Korpen so the form is submitted to google? The log is trying to log a form named threadForm, does it show an actual form element in the lot (you can click on it or hover your mouse over it in firebug and it'll show you on the page what element it is). What version of jQuery are you using, you can type `$.fn.jquery` in the console

Comment: Yes, it is. When I clicked the entry in the log and navigated my way to document it showed me information about the html-document that was accurate for the page in question and when I selected the form in the list of document information it showed me the attributes and elements of the form.
I'm using jquery version 1.11.1

Comment: @Korpen Updated the answer, I think you're attaching the event handler wrong, I don't see document ready in your code but you commented that you're using that. Take a look at the example, even though it doesn't use document ready the code is located after the html elements that it uses so it's not needed.

Comment: @Korpen Just see that you put document ready inside validatepost function, I don't think you understand what document ready does and why to use it so suggest reading the jquery documentation on that. Then wrap attaching the event handler inside a document ready

Comment: I just updated the code to how it is right now. Please, correct me if I'm wrong but, if I have submit attachment wrapped by the document ready and the validatepost is called by the submit attachment, isn't document ready obsolete in validatepost?

Comment: @Korpen yes, you don't need document ready in validatepost, you should make the suggested changes to update_post as well but that has nothing to do with the form being submitted to google

Comment: Also, I tried putting the script after the form in the html-doc but that didn't do anything either. It even sends me off to google, when I try it.

Comment: I have refactored my code pretty heavily and the script-tags are in a file called _head that is included (js has worked before I introduced ajax så nothing wrong with that). I just tried putting the script tags in my file _footer which is the end of the body and which is also always called with content in the right place. It didn't change anything.